# "import x" vs "from x import y" clashes, how do I fix?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

I have loads of different scripts and whenever I try and merge them all together I get tons of problems, for example in one script im using:

```
import os.path
from time import time, sleep, strftime, mktime
from datetime import date, timedelta, datetime
```

Now in my second script I have:

```
import os.path, time
from datetime import date, timedelta, datetime

with open('test.txt') as filetoread:
    last_check = float(filetoread.read())

fulldate = time.ctime(os.path.getctime("../main.xml"))
struct = time.strptime(fulldate)
filetime = datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(struct))
filedate = filetime.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)

if last_check != 1:
    if last_check+ 1 <= time.time():
        if str(filetime)[:10] != str(datetime.now())[:10]:
            with open("test.txt", 'wb') as filetowrite:
                filetowrite.write(str(time.time()))
                print "time wrote"
        else:
            with open("test.txt", 'wb') as filetowrite:
                filetowrite.write("1")
                print "correct"
    else:
        if str(filetime)[:10] == str(datetime.now())[:10]:
            with open("test.txt", 'wb') as filetowrite:
                filetowrite.write("1")
                print "correct"
        else:
            print "30 mins not up"
else:
    print "correct"
```

Now when I try to change the imports to:

```
import os.path
from time import time, sleep, strftime, mktime, ctime
from datetime import date, timedelta, datetime
```

I get the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\testimports.py", line 40, in <module>
    fulldate = time.ctime(os.path.getctime("../main.xml"))
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'ctime'
```

I personally prefer the `import time, datetime, os.path, os` route over importing all of the different parts of the module.

Any advice?

Comment: *I personally prefer the import time, datetime, os.path, os route*. Then **why change it**? Your exception simply can be solved by changing `time.ctime()` to `ctime()`.

Comment: What's the problem? You have two separate files that aren't interfering with each other. The only issue is that you've done `from time import time` and then tried to use `time.ctime`, which doesn't exist. You either have to use just `crime`, which you've already imported, or as Martijn said, just import `time` and explicitly use `time.time` and `time.ctime`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You imported `time.ctime()` as a global name now, *as well* as the `time.time()` function:

```
from time import time, sleep, strftime, mktime, ctime
```

so `time.ctime()` now refers to an attribute of the `time.time()` function.

Change your reference:

```
fulldate = ctime(os.path.getctime("../main.xml"))
```

The question remains then, *why did you change it*. It is perfectly fine to limit the number of globals by importing just the module object into your globals.